# ValidateScript ParameterAttribute in C# Binary PowerShell Module

Tags: c#, powershell, binary, powershell-module

I have recently begun experimenting with Binary PowerShell Programming in C#, and I am having some trouble with ParameterValidationAttributes, the ValidateScript Attribute mostly.  Basically, i want to create a Param named "ComputerName" and validate the computer is online at that time.  It was easy in PowerShell:

```
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({ if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1) { $true } else { throw "Unable to connect to $_." }})]
    [String]
    $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
```

But i cannot figure out how to replicate that in C#.  the ValidateScript attribute takes a ScriptBlock object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock(v=vs.85).aspx im just not sure how to create that in C#, and i cannot really find any examples.

```
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = true)]
[ValidateScript(//Code Here//)]
public string ComputerName { get; set; }
```

C# is very new to me, so i appologize if this is a dumb question.  here is a link the ValidateScript Attribute Class:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.validatescriptattribute(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible in C#, since .NET only allow compile time constants, `typeof` expressions and array creation expressions for attribute parameters and only constant available for reference types other then `string` is `null`. Instead you should derive from `ValidateArgumentsAttribute` and override `Validate` to perform validation:

```
class ValidateCustomAttribute:ValidateArgumentsAttribute {
    protected override void Validate(object arguments,EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics) {
        //Custom validation code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, this maybe a little out of my conception of C#.  So, after i create that Class can i just call it in the ValidateScript()?

[ValidateScript({ValidateCustomAttribute.Validate(arg0, arg1)})]

Comment: @dotps1 You apply your custom attribute instead of `ValidateScriptAttribute`.

Comment: Thanks, i think i understand, so i can just throw an Exception if the computer cannot be contacted?

Comment: @dotps1 Yes, by throwing exception, you notify PowerShell that given argument does not pass validation.

Comment: ok, so here is what i have:
`[Parameter()]
[ValidateComputerName()]
public string ComputerName {get; set;}
// cmdlet here


class ValidateComputerNameAttribute : ValidateArgumentsAttribute
{
    protected override void Validate(object arguments, EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics)
    {
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            ping.Send(arguments.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new SystemException("The specified system could not be contacted.");
        }
    }
}`
Just wanted to ask if that looks ok, im still amateur at C#

Comment: It looks ok for me, but you should be noted that `Ping.Send` does not throw if destination unreachable, so you should check returned value.

Comment: This is great @user4003407 but I'd love to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on user4003407's answer above with a more complete example.

Derive a new validator from ValidateArgumentsAttribute and override Validate to perform validation.  Validate is void so you really just get to throw exceptions in cases you choose.

Kevin Marquette has an excellent [article](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-02-20-Powershell-creating-parameter-validators-and-transforms/) but it's in powershell. Here is a c# example:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "ExampleCommand")]
public class GetSolarLunarName : PSCmdlet
{   
    [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline = true, Mandatory = true)]
    [ValidateDateTime()]
    public DateTime UtcDateTime { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {

        var ExampleOutput = //Your code
        this.WriteObject(ExampleOutput);
        base.EndProcessing();
    }
}

class ValidateDateTime:ValidateArgumentsAttribute {
protected override void Validate(object arguments,EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics) {
    var date = (DateTime)arguments;
    if( date.Year < 1700 || date.Year > 2082){
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

}
```