# Method Parameter Validation Attribute

Tags: c#

Powershell offers a `ValidateScript` parameter attribute to check given attributes. Example:

```
function foo{
    Param(
       [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})] 
       [string]
       $FilePath,
    ....
```

Is there an equivalent available in C#, to validate parameters of a method? So that I can define a method in c# like:

```
...
public static string Foo (
   [Validate(p => p <1)]
   int p) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please share some more light on what this param does for PS.

Comment: Yes, of cause. Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.validatescriptattribute%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
Powershell is built on .NET Framework, so it can access all classes of standart library.
Also, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908470/validatescript-parameterattribute-in-c-sharp-binary-powershell-module), maybe it can help you.

Comment: The closest thing in c# are [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Igor: I`ve update my question. I'm interested at parameter checking "just in general".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check namespace Dataannotation namespace in c# this will validate property with the help of attribute.